# Why does window.open(...).onunload = function () { ... } not work as I expect?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, window.open, window.onunload

I want to be able to tell when a window that I open is closed by the user.  This is the code of my attempt at monitoring this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.document.onready = function () {
            document.getElementById('openWindow').onclick = function () {
                var windowref = window.open('tests2.html');
                windowref.onunload =  function () {
                    window.alert('hola!');
                };
            };
        };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id='openWindow'>Open Window</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I would expect this to alert "hola!" in the original window after the window that was opened with `window.open` was closed.  Instead, it alerts "hola!" in the original window immediately after opening the new window with `window.open`.  Why does it work like this?  Is there a way of doing what I want to do?

Comment: What about changing `window.alert` to `windowref.alert`?

Comment: @pimvdb The problem isn't with where the alert is coming from, it's with when the alert is being shown.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The window first loads with a blank page and then unloads the page, causing the `unload` event.
Your page then loads. Try attaching the event when the `onload` event fires to avoid this.

[Simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DigitalPlane/5GFFw/)

```
document.getElementById('openWindow').onclick = function () {
      var windowref = window.open('tests2.html');
      windowref.onload = function() {
            windowref.onunload =  function () {
                window.alert('hola!');
            };
      }
};
```

Comment: I think jsfiddle.net is doing something funky.  Clearly, your demo works, but try to put it into an empty HTML page.  I can't get it to work in a normal HTML page.  The `window.onload` event is never fired.

Comment: Actually, it looks like I was doing something funky.  It seems to have to do with the way I was serving the files (via the filesystem instead of a web server).  It probably had to do with a same-origin restriction.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if domain of the new window is different from the parent. It doesn't work even if I run Chrome with `--disable-web-security`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding after the window loads

```
document.getElementById('openWindow').onclick = function () {
    var windowref = window.open('tests2.html');
    windowref.window.onload = function(){  //wait til load to add onunload event
        windowref.window.onunload =  function () {
            window.alert('hola!');
        };
    }
};
```

[JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/uguwec/)

Comment: Modern browsers have new rules from not allowing certain actions on window close, this might be one of them now. Maybe onbeforeunload will work.

Comment: can you please assist me for working with modern browser ?

The above code doesn't work if i write "window.open('http://google.com')"........... else only workes if the URL same as parent.

Answer (score 1):

Digital Plane answer seems to work, but it feels a bit brittle (e.g. if the browser changed behavior and stopped loading/unloading "about:blank" the event would stop firing.)

My solution was to check `windowref.location.href` of the popup and skip the handler when it is "about:blank":

```js
document.getElementById('openWindow').onclick = function () {
    var windowref = window.open('tests2.html');
    windowref.addEventListener('unload', () => {
        if (windowref.location.href === "about:blank")
            return;
        window.alert('hola!');
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Very late response to this one, but I've just had the same issue with this code in an aspx page:

```
function handleButton() {
    var myPopup = window.open('/Home/MyPopup', 'Popup');
    myPopup.addEventListener("unload", function (x) {
        console.log(x.results);
    });
}


<button onclick="handleButton()">My Button</button>
```

My mistake was to omit giving the button a `type="button"`, so the page defaults to `type="submit"` and posts back when the button is clicked (I assume removing the reference to the event listener when the page reloads). Giving the button a type of button fixed the issue:

```
<button type="button" onclick="handleButton()">My Button</button>
```